# Unable to start uchiwa (sensu dashboard)

Tags: dashboard, sensu

Attempt to start uchiwa fails with no error when starting via init.d script and no process.

No output in /var/log/uchiwa.log

Output found in `/var/log/uchiwa.err`:

```
/opt/uchiwa/bin/uchiwa: 1: /opt/uchiwa/bin/uchiwa: cannot create ^A: Permission denied
/opt/uchiwa/bin/uchiwa: 1: /opt/uchiwa/bin/uchiwa: ^?ELF^B^A^A^B: not found
/opt/uchiwa/bin/uchiwa: 2: /opt/uchiwa/bin/uchiwa: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
I also ensured permissions in the /etc/sensu directory was correct with:


vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:~$ ls -la /etc/sensu/
total 44
drwxr-xr-x  8 sensu sensu 4096 Mar 17 10:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 99 root  root  4096 Mar 27 00:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 sensu sensu 4096 Mar 17 09:53 conf.d
-rw-r--r--  1 sensu sensu  218 Mar 11 05:08 config.json
-rw-r--r--  1 sensu sensu  683 Mar  2 02:29 config.json.example
drwxr-xr-x  2 sensu sensu 4096 Mar 17 10:13 dashboard.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 sensu sensu 4096 Mar  2 02:29 extensions
drwxr-xr-x  2 sensu sensu 4096 Mar  2 02:29 handlers
drwxr-xr-x  2 sensu sensu 4096 Mar  2 02:29 mutators
drwxr-xr-x  2 sensu sensu 4096 Mar  2 02:29 plugins
-rw-r--r--  1 sensu sensu  201 Mar 17 10:15 uchiwa.json


vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/opt/uchiwa$ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 10:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 10:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 17 10:13 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 17 10:13 src
```

Any idea why this may not be working? Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

There was indeed a permission problem which I resolved by giving the correct permissions which has now resolved:

```
  /opt/uchiwa/bin/uchiwa: 1: /opt/uchiwa/bin/uchiwa: cannot create ^A: Permission denied
```

However the following errors still persist:

```
/opt/uchiwa/bin/uchiwa: 1: /opt/uchiwa/bin/uchiwa: ^?ELF^B^A^A^B: not found
/opt/uchiwa/bin/uchiwa: 2: /opt/uchiwa/bin/uchiwa: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I have reinstalling the package but it still looks corrupt.

Comment: To me it looks like a problem with the permissions with uchiwa and not with sensu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the 32 bits binary package contains a 64 bits binary: https://github.com/sensu/uchiwa/issues/457

Installing version 0.13.0-1 seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your Uchiwa directory is owned by `root` and not the `sensu` user. You are logged into your Vagrant image as user `vagrant`. I would give ownership of the `/opt/uchiwa` directory to `sensu` with `chown`. Next run the `uchiwa` binary as the `sensu` user.